# MVC Bootstrap CSS Layout Left Alignment

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

Which **Bootstrap** field here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/
will help me control left alignment?

Trying to customize a default startup MVC application homepage.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your code?
In Bootstrap there is no left margin control since everything is responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not post any code i will take a guess.

Have you used `<div class="container">`?
If yes, try to replace it with `<div class="container-fluid">`. This will make your content fit to the whole side instead of resizing it to a vertical bar in the middle.

You should also read up on [fluid-containers in bootstrap](https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.6/docs/css/#grid-example-fluid)

---

EDIT: If you really just want to adjust the container size you need to change those values at [bootstrap container-sized](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/#container-sizes) which is the size of the 'vertical content bar'-width

Comment: are you allowed to 1+ my question by the way? not sure if this breaks stack overflow rules, but trying to acquire if I ever place question on Bounty , Thanks

Comment: I actually don't know why i shouldn't be allowed to do so?
Please ask this on stackoverflow meta since this is an SO related question.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net MVC has folders Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title – приложение ASP.NET</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("WebApp", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Calculator", "Calculator", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year – application ASP.NET</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

It is template for site.

You can add css property for example `.yourcontainer`:

```
<div class="container body-content yourcontaine">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year – application ASP.NET</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

And write the necessary properties:

```
.yourcontaine{
    /*your properties*/
}
```

Or change HTML to:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year – application ASP.NET</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need **pull-left**. Apply this class to master div container.

Attaching screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works, I guess my next question I should have asked how to stretch it right also so it is displayed across whole screen, adding pull-right after pull-left at the end does not work, Thanks

Comment: Ohk @AppleBook89, have tried **container-fluid** class replacing "container"?

Comment: For those migrating to, or using Bootstrap 4, `pull-left` and `pull-right` have been deprecated in favour of `float-left` and `float-right`. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#utilities